# Run Shell Script inside tmux

Tags: command-line, server, bash, ssh, nginx

Why after running tmux on a remote server via ssh, program works; but after detaching sessions, it returns 404?

This is a Go(golang) program, a http server listening on a port, behind a nginx reverse proxy.

First data: everything works fine like this:

1 - I connect to the server using `ssh user@server-ip`,

2 - run `tmux`,

3 - run this script inside `tmux` session, by `. my-script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

go build -v

exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>/tmp/myapi.log 2>&1

export API_COUCHDB_ADMIN='admin'
export API_COUCHDB_PASSWORD='************'
export API_COUCHDB_URL='http://172.17.0.2:5984/'
# [some other env variables ...]
./myapi
```

4 - detach the tmux session by *Ctrl-b* and then *d*.

So far so good! Everything works fine inside a browser on address `http://www.myapi-consumer.com` and the ssh terminal is still open; but

5 - when I detach the ssh session (by *Ctrl+a and d*), the program no longer works correctly and returns 404 (it's the one sending 404).

6 - Now when I reconnect to the remote server using `ssh user@server-ip` then again it works as expected and I am testing the "working" part on another connection - on my cell phone with another internet connection.

What is happening?

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171503/tmux-session-killed-when-disconnecting-from-ssh) might be the problem (and a solution)

Comment: This is such a pain. There's a plethora of different solutions for this problem & yet it's simple: closing the damn terminal without touching anything by OS. Apparently it's not just the sockets but also stdin/out/err thing too. `screen`, `tmux`, `nohub` and no-luck! BTW Thanks for the link - though I do not get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the app is serving files that reside inside home directory, which gets unmounted when disconnecting.

I've got the answer from golang-nuts group [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/jDuEKPgJKH8/Tzh5DOfkBwAJ).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am understanding.

You saying you are exiting the session or closing current terminal session. A program running and you just closed your terminal , it will no longer run.

But you are using `tmux` and thats all `tmux` for, to run the programs in background.

Try running the program by placing it from background. I mean

`nohup myscript.sh &`

`nohup` to run your script even you sign off , `&[and]` to push your script into background.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Raja, OP is running the program in a `tmux` session, not the regular shell session..

Comment: @heemayl I have updated already , please reload.

Comment: If OP is already using `tmux` session, then why would he need `nohup` and backgrounding?

Comment: @heemayl I am asking him to try and I am not saying this is damn sure straight answer

Comment: Thanks! The program works as expected after reconnecting just to the ssh. So it's already running back in tmux. Please see updates.